# Adding a request parameter to logs in python

Tags: python, logging, fastapi

I have a FastAPI application. When it gets a request it calls a bunch of async methods that generate a lot of logs. I want to add a prefix to every line of the logs for a particular request with a parameter from that request (which is a request ID from another application).

Right now I am manually adding the parameter to the logs using formatted strings like

```py
logger.info(f"[{data['request_id']}] ...")
```

Is there a way to automatically prefix the logs of a request with a parameter from that request?

Answer (score 0):

Either you pass the request object manually each time to the functions and then the functions use the data from the request object, or you store a so called "state" of the request somewhere (e.g. a database) and retrieve it from the different functions. Still, the latter method requires some kind of communication between the endpoint function and the functions that are being called.

For the rest, I'm not aware of any other method that can accomplish what you're asking. Maybe there are some logging libraries that allow for such a thing, but I don't know any of those.